# Texmaker does not import overleaf project

Tags: texmaker, font-encodings, overleaf

Can i import project(.zip) from overleaf on Texmaker? Every time i try to open the .zip, Texmaker ask me to choose a enconding and even if i choose utf8 (I'm using utf8 in overleaf)  all my text turn into weird simbols like this:

�l���z2�(Q�Ę"5�ؑ
�!� v,f�����7�'�"���\0LЗ�&Y�s��w�\N�T\�/ne*�ė�?�A6'r���D}ím�=�ȋGA4n�7��vמ�i�$���Ϲ��E�_��D�$�|��L��8��2t����U�~��� �Y迼��c"-o��2�&"�D��Ƒ狑��P�~�@�<�����������k?��

Comment: sorry, i writed utf by mistake.

Comment: You'd have to extract the .zip into a folder. Afterwards open your main file (with .tex extension) in Texmaker.